# How do I maintain the status of the check box?

Tags: php, checkbox

After selecting the check box, the check box values and the sum values are reset when the next page is passed. How should I modify it?

PHP code:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        
                echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<td > <input  name='amount' type='checkbox' value ='" . $row['amount'] . " ' onclick='totalIt()'></td>";    
                
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
                echo "</tbody>";                            
                echo "</table>";
                echo " <input value='￦0' readonly='readonly' type='text' name='total' />";
                // Free result set
                mysqli_free_result($result);
```

JavaScript code:

```
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("amount");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "￦" + total;
}
```

and How can I check one more value in advance?

Comment: can you use a session to store it's values?

Comment: @Saud Yes. possible

Comment: Okay. Can you describe in detail what you're trying to achieve? Because if you're just want php to maintain a state/values in the next page too, you can store them in session and fetch it in your next page.

Comment: @Saud What I want is to subtract the addition in real time.
It was a large amount of data, so I did PageNation.
Select data on the first page and click on the second page to reset the checkbox and value.

Comment: Ok. You could store your total amount in session and get it from there. Later you can add/subtract your desired value from it using js.

Comment: @Saud Thanks.  I Will try it